# Axios Spy not being called correct number of times in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a React context I am testing that runs a single function to check for an application update. The `checkForUpdate` function looks like this:

```
 async function checkForUpdate() {
    if (isPlatform('capacitor')) {
      const maintanenceURL =
        'https://example.com/maintenance.json';
      const updateURL =
        'https://example.com/update.json';

      try {
        const maintanenceFetch: AxiosResponse<MaintanenceDataInterface> =
          await axios.get(maintanenceURL);
        console.log('maintain', maintanenceFetch);

        if (maintanenceFetch.data.enabled) {
          setUpdateMessage(maintanenceFetch.data.msg);
          return;
        }

        const updateFetch: AxiosResponse<UpdateDataInterface> = await axios.get(
          updateURL
        );
        console.log('updateFetch', updateFetch);

        if (updateFetch.data.enabled) {
          const capApp = await App.getInfo();
          const capAppVersion = capApp.version;

          console.log('Thi is a thinkg', capAppVersion);

          if (isPlatform('android')) {
            console.log('hi');
            const { currentAndroid, majorMsg, minorMsg } = updateFetch.data;
            const idealVersionArr = currentAndroid.split('.');
            const actualVersionArr = capAppVersion.split('.');

            if (idealVersionArr[0] !== actualVersionArr[0]) {
              setUpdateMessage(majorMsg);
              setUpdateAvailable(true);
              return;
            }

            if (idealVersionArr[1] !== actualVersionArr[1]) {
              setUpdateMessage(minorMsg);
              setUpdateAvailable(true);
              return;
            }
          } else {
            const { currentIos, majorMsg, minorMsg } = updateFetch.data;
            const idealVersionArr = currentIos.split('.');
            const actualVersionArr = capAppVersion.split('.');

            if (idealVersionArr[0] !== actualVersionArr[0]) {
              setUpdateMessage(majorMsg);
              setUpdateAvailable(true);
              return;
            }

            if (idealVersionArr[1] !== actualVersionArr[1]) {
              setUpdateMessage(minorMsg);
              setUpdateAvailable(true);
              return;
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error in checkForUpdate', err);
      }
    }
  }
```

For some reason, in my test I wrote to test this, my axiosSpy only shows that it has been called 1 time instead of the expected 2 times. The console logs I posted for both get requests run as well. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is the test:

```
it.only('should render the update page if the fetch call to update bucket is enabled and returns a different major version', async () => {
      const isPlatformSpy = jest.spyOn(ionicReact, 'isPlatform');
      isPlatformSpy.mockReturnValueOnce(true).mockReturnValueOnce(true);

      const appSpy = jest.spyOn(App, 'getInfo');
      appSpy.mockResolvedValueOnce({
        version: '0.8.0',
        name: 'test',
        build: '123',
        id: 'r132-132',
      });

      const axiosSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
      axiosSpy
        .mockResolvedValueOnce({
          data: {
            enabled: false,
            msg: {
              title: 'App maintenance',
              msg: 'We are currently solving an issue where users cannot open the app. This should be solved by end of day 12/31/2022! Thank you for your patience ',
              btn: 'Ok',
              type: 'maintenance',
            },
          },
        })
        .mockResolvedValueOnce({
          data: {
            current: '1.0.0',
            currentAndroid: '1.0.0',
            currentIos: '2.0.0',
            enabled: true,
            majorMsg: {
              title: 'Important App update',
              msg: 'Please update your app to the latest version to continue using it. If you are on iPhone, go to the app store and search MO Gas Tax Back to update your app. The button below does not work but will in the current update!',
              btn: 'Download',
              type: 'major',
            },
            minorMsg: {
              title: 'App update available',
              msg: "There's a new version available, would you like to get it now?",
              btn: 'Download',
              type: 'minor',
            },
          },
        });

      customRender(<UpdateChild />);

      expect(axiosSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    });
```

Comment: did you add jest.mock('axios') at the top?

Comment: Yes it is mocked at the top @NimaKa